# Allow registration with duplicate usernames in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, registration

I have used [Awo Email Login Plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/email-authentication/16096) to allow user login using email address and now I want user to allow registration using duplicate name but unique email ID. Is there any module or solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found solution updated registration.xml and change username as type hidden and assigns email field value to that hidden box using jQuery. Now DB stores username as email ID :)

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for an opensource or a commercial one?

may be you can also try this if you are looking for a free one. instead of free one it takes email address as username

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/email-authentication/16246

hope this helps

Comment: It does only allow me to login using either username or email ID, I want to allow user to user duplicate username while registration e.g. 2 David with different email IDs

Comment: is that ok if i edit  a little of an extension to suit the need? and in this case user will be able to login through email adress  but not username....

Comment: I have already that but I want user to register with same (duplicate) name e.g. two david can register with different email IDs :)